# jquery alternate link onerror?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onerror

My jquery application includes in the html a link to a document hosted on a server which will not be accessible for some users. I can host a copy of the document on another server.

I want users to be directed to the copy if they cannot access the original. But to access the original if possible.

I thought:

```
    <a href="http://www.theoriginal.org"     onerror="http://www.thecopy.org">Link</a>
```

but that is ignored. I see plenty of questions and answers about broken images but not much about other types of links.

If relevant, the "original" link is inserted by some javascript.

I tried the suggested Ajax code, using google's home page as my example url and unfortunately ran into this: "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.google.co.nz/. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS. "
So I can't test the existence of the page this way.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an ajax request and based on the response code change the link href

```
<a class="if-not-working" data-replace-with="http://thecopy.org" href="http://www.theoriginal.org">Link</a>
```

JS:

```
$('.if-not-working').each(function(){
  $this = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    'url': $this.attr('href'),
    statusCode: {
      400: function() {
        $this.attr('href', $this.data('replace-with'));
      },
      404: function() {
        $this.attr('href', $this.data('replace-with'));
      },
      500: function() {
        $this.attr('href', $this.data('replace-with'));
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the general jQuery/ajax code to check whether the document exists:

```
    $.ajax({
    url:'example.html',
    type:'HEAD',
    error: function()
    {
        //file not exists
        $('a').attr('href', 'backup.html');
    },
    success: function()
    {
        //file exists
        $('a').attr('href', ''example.html'');
    }
});
```

If you have a lot of links on your page that needs a backup link, You can make it a function by looping through all the links in your page and passing the backup link within it, otherwise looping through the whole page is an overkill.

Comment: Will this work given that the original file is on a different server (not the one hosting the application) ...I'm seeing plenty about ajax queries not working across domains.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I thought you are saying the original file is on your server. What I understand is both files are being hosted on two different servers and non of the servers are yours. Is that right?!

Comment: My server has the "backup" file. The original and preferred file is on another server which is inaccessible to an important subset of users.